# Why does the suffix “able” sometimes have the meaning of obligation in words such as payable or answerable?

Tags: meaning, etymology, suffixes

According to the Merriam-Webster online dictionary,
the meanings of *responsible*, *answerable*, and *payable*
are

> responsible: liable to be called on to answer

> answerable: liable to be called to account

> payable: that may, can, or must be paid.

They all include the meaning of obligation rather than the straightforward meaning of the suffix, the one of capability as in *durable*, whose meaning in the online dictionary is

> durable: able to exist for a long time without significant deterioration in quality or value.

In the case of *responsible*, it seems possible to argue that the suffix gives to the word the meaning of freedom or opportunity that the adjective *able* has as in

> You are able to skate on the lake today. The ice is thick enough.

Then, the sentence below may mean he has the right to decide everything about recruiting and training.

> He is responsible for recruiting and training new staff.

But, such interpretation seems impossible for the other two words.

Why does the suffix *able* sometimes have the meaning of obligation in words such as payable or answerable?

(I found two similar questions. [One](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/556557/differentiating-the-meaning-of-the-able-suffix-able-to-be-vs-to-be) is about how to tell whether the suffix has the meaning of ability or that of obligation. My question is about why the suffix has the meaning of obligation.
[The other](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210082/does-able-have-an-imperative-meaning) has not been given a proper answer because, in my opinion, the words used as examples are uncommon words.)

Comment: The suffix _-able/-ible_ is a modal, and all modals have epistemic and deontic senses. Deontic senses have to do with permission and obligation. _Responsible (for)_ refers to an obligation -- what must be done. _Payable_ asserts that something must be paid, and _answerable_ has the same sense as _responsible_.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [How did "-able" semantically shift to mean "requiring"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/557027/191178) But the answers are not great.

Comment: Thank you @JohnLawler . I didn't know suffixes have a function as a modal. Could you give me other examples of suffixes (or perhaps prefixes) which are also modals?  Or, -able is exceptional in this regard?

Comment: @Laurel Yes, it is basically  the same question as mine, but  I think the answers there are not convincing.

Comment: Please take more care in your use of English. Two basic mistakes in your title are hardly a good advertisement for your question. If you have a word processor on your computer, set the language to English and then do a grammar check. It won’t be perfect, but it might pick up the difference in forms of the verb to have, between “it has” and “it does have”.

Comment: @David thank you for correcting the title. Yes, I'll take more care in my use of English.

Comment: It is wise not to rely upon one dictionary - check several dictionaries for meaning in context,

Answer (score 2):

The suffix *-able/-ible*, like the word *able*, is a modal; *be able to* is one paraphrase of one sense of *can*.

Like all modals, *-able* has two senses:

- a **deontic** permission/obligation sense
  *This veil is permissible; That word is not publishable.*

and

- an **epistemic** possibility/probability sense (most common in negatives)
  *This equation is impossible/improbable; The house is barely habitable.*

If you look, you'll find all modals have dual meanings; some have more.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does suffix -able sometimes has the meaning of obligation in words such as payable or answerable?

I'm not sure why you'd think there must be a reason for the suffix *-able* to have "the meaning of obligation" and, more importantly, that we should be able to find such a reason.

If that's a legitimate question, you can also ask, "Why does the suffix *-able* sometimes have the meaning of capability?", which I'd think you know you can't.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-able) does say the suffix has two meanings:

> variants *or less commonly* -ible 
> 1 : capable of, fit for, or worthy of (being so acted upon or toward) —chiefly in adjectives derived from verbs
> breakable
> collectible
> 2 : tending, given, or **liable** to
> agreeable
> perishable

(Boldface mine.)

Comment: I don't ask "Why does the suffix -able sometimes have the meaning of capability?" because the adjective *able* has the meaning.

Comment: @Aki Just because an adjective has a certain meaning doesn't mean a suffix with the same or similar form as the adjective should have the same meaning.

Comment: So, why is that? I think it is a legitimate question.  Do they have different etymological origins, for example? Or, the adjective *able* too has the meaning of obligation, which I think John Lawler's answer suggests.

Comment: @Aki No, John Lawler didn't talk about the adjective _able_. He only talked about the suffix. It's not a legitimate question, because you erroneously assume that the suffix _-able_ must have a meaning corresponding to the adjective _able_.

Comment: I think he talks about modality in general. You assume there is no connection between the adjective and the suffix. Do you also think there is no connection between the adjective *full* and the suffix *-ful*?

Comment: Both the adjective _able_ (mostly as a predicate adjective with infinitive complement _He's able to do that now_) and the suffix _-able_ from the same source are modals semantically, and have several meanings (and many idioms). [Modality](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) is a **very** complex topic.

Comment: @Aki It's one thing to think that there is some connection between the adj. _able_ and the suffix _able_, but it's an entirely different thing to assume that you should be able to explain why the suffix has some other meanings than the adjective.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you suggesting that the adjective _able_ can denote obligation?

Comment: No, merely that it's a modal word. Obligation, like permission, is a matter of the meaning of individual modals in individual contexts.

Comment: @JK2 But, meanings don't come from nowhere. I think I have the answer thanks to John Lawler. A modal word, whether it is an adjective or a suffix, has both epistemic and deontic senses. Which sense comes up to the surface depends on the context. I even think that there could be a context the adjective *able* has the meaning of obligation, even though the closest example I have come up with is "You could ask before you borrow my car" from Practical English Usage by M. Swan"